# Magento 500 internal server error after upgrade to 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've just upgraded a dev site to magento version 1.7.0.1.

I have an internal server error on the front and back end of the site.  I can access the downloader/index.php fine and I can install and check for updates or extensions.

I have changed the permissions on index.php and downloader/index.php to 644 as instructed on many sites.  var/cache has been cleared.  var/sessions is timing out when I try to access.  The magento cleanup tool just appears to crash or continue running and never completes.  Options +FollowSymLinks has been commented out of the .htaccess file.  The php_value memory_limit on the htaccess was also tested at different amounts and is currently set at 1024M.  The server has also been restarted completely.

Any help to get rid of this http 500 internal server error would be great.

Comment: What webserver (Apache, Nginx, LightHttpd, IIS, ..) are you using? Anything in the system, webserver or PHP error logs?

Comment: yes, all you have to do is to check all error logs, and remember - never restart your server. it`s easier to restart one particular "service" like php-fpm, apache, mysql etc

Answer (score 1):

You should check your index.php file permission, I had to change the permission of the index.php file to 0644, and it solved in my case, also  you should check  at the error log, then you should get answer,